# Relational database design for a a specific Scenario

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have a Business Scenario where the Products can have multiple variants example 100ml, 200ml, 500ml etc and out of all those variants only one of them can be a Standard Variant and I have a database column IsStandardVariant to specify a Standard Variant of a product. I am not able to figure out which all columns to make unique. If I make ProductId and IsStandardVarriant Unique it would not allow me to store values with non standard variant Example I have a row as
1 200ml 1
1 500ml 0
I cant store a row 1 777ml 0 
I cant either make all 3 of them as unique as it would allow for another variant to be stored
Example
 1 400ml 1
 1 300ml 1
Please help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot model the data the way you are trying to, utilizing just one table, for the reasons you mentioned in your question. You would need to use two tables for the same.

The master table would be ProductMaster table and it would have ProductId and Volume columns. The master table would have a unique key with both ProductId and Volume columns.

The other table would be StandardVariantLookUp table which would have the ProductId and Volume columns but the volume in this table would be the volume for the standard Variant only. This table would have unique key with just ProductId so that you can have only one row per product.

Also in addition, you would setup a referential integrity between the ProductMaster and StandardVariantLookup tables on the ProductId so that the productid column of StandardVariantLookup references ProductId column of ProductMaster tabel. So if a record needs to be inserted into StandVariantLookup, the product should be already defined in the ProductMaster table.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Products pair (product, variant) unique. Then you would also like a constraint that there is only one TRUE value for isStandardVariant per product. Most DBMSs can't enforce that declaratively.

You can instead have a table ProductVariant with columns (product, variant) and another table ProductStandardVariant with columns (product, variant) with a foreign key on (product, variant) to ProductVariant. This is the straightforward relational design.